# Using dictionary as parameters with request API in python

Tags: python, api, request

I'm working with the request API to run a get request from the gravity form API from wordpress, and having some difficulty in using the search function in the params field. Below is the working code which I tried at the beginning.

```
url = "https://websitename.com/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/100/entries?search={\"start_date\":\"2021-10-01\",\"end_date\":\"2021-10-30\"}"

params={"_field_ids":"id,date_created","paging[page_size]":"100"}

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic Key',
  'Cookie': 'session'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=params)
```

However, when I changed the param into like this

```
params={"search":{"start_date":"2021-07-01","end_date":"2021-07-31"},"_field_ids":"id,date_created","paging[page_size]":"100"}
```

It does not work anymore.

I found some resources to put the date range dictionary into a list like this, but it still not working.

```
params={"search":[{"start_date":"2021-07-01","end_date":"2021-07-31"}],"_field_ids":"id,date_created","paging[page_size]":"100"}
```

Please help me!!!!

Comment: did you try `requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, json=params)`

Comment: Hi @Epsi95,
I tried with your suggestion and it does not work as well.
It return me this error
`{'code': 'rest_invalid_param',
 'message': 'Invalid parameter(s): search',
 'data': {'status': 400,
  'params': {'search': 'search is not of type string.'},
  'details': {'search': {'code': 'rest_invalid_type',
    'message': 'search is not of type string.',
    'data': {'param': 'search'}}}}}`

Comment: there can be multiple cause, can you provide minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Sorry @Epsi95, I cannot share anything else other than this code as it is retrieving the organization data
`url = "https://websitename.com/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/100/entries"
params={"search":{"start_date":"2021-07-01","end_date":"2021-07-31"},"_field_ids":"id,date_created","paging[page_size]":"100"}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic key',
  'Cookie': 'session id'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)`

Comment: Are there anything else that you need me to provide in order to identify the root cause like api documentation?

Comment: Have you tried making the value of `params["search"]` a string, e.g. `…"search":"{\"start_date\":\"…`? It might be easier to mix single and double quotes rather than escaping them.

Comment: Hi @importrandom, yes I have tried that and it does not work as well.

Comment: Hi @importrandom, sorry I have missed the " in front of this part {\"start_date\":\". I have tried with your suggestion and it is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the details of the fix. This will help in case future folks find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make the param search become a string by adding ", which is like `…"search":"{\"start_date\":\"…`

The full code will look like this.

```
url = "https://websitename.com/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/100/entries"

params={"search":"{\"start_date\":\"2021-10-01\",\"end_date\":\"2021-10-30\"}","_field_ids":"id,date_created","paging[page_size]":"100"}

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic Key',
  'Cookie': 'session'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

Comment: If someone wants to use `"typ": "FFWCSX"` as a value of a dictionary, it can be `params = {"filter": "{\"typ\":\"FFWCSX\"}", "count": 500}`